# Signal Problem of S8+

Tags: networking, mobile-network

I recently bought a Samsung S8+. The phone is alright but I got stuck in a problem. One of the network provider SIM is not working. As a simulation, I used following steps:

1. I exchange the slots, other sim was working fine on that slot.
2. I bought another sim of the same network provider and tested in both slots, still no service.
3. I moved to a region out of my university, that was working fine, as soon as I entered back, then again no service.
4. I put the same network provider sim in other phone at exactly the same location where s8+ was giving zero signals, the sim was providing full signal, hence it came out that the problem of signal jam was out of concern.
5. I restarted, factory reset the phone, but still the problem persists.

P.S I recently bought and in two days, I noticed the problem.
I got stuck in this complicated situation. Help me out, I will be grateful.
Thanks.